# Sql to get a specific result from table rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I use mysql and I need a sql to get a table result with some rows.

I'd better to show with a sample

tableA

```
id, autfis_id, name, col1, col2 ...... coln
1,1,a, col1_content ... coln_content
2,1,a, col1_content ... coln_content
3,2,c, col1_content ... coln_content
4,1,a, col1_content ... coln_content
5,2,c, col1_content ... coln_content
6,3,d, col1_content ... coln_content
```

Expected Result

```
id,autfis_id,count(rows with same autfis_id), name, col1 ..... coln
1,1,3,a, col1_content ... coln_content
3,2,2,c, col1_content ... coln_content
6,3,1,d, col1_content ... coln_content
```

where id is the first id found from rows containing the same 'autfis_id'

Comment: how is *first id* defined? smallest? and what's rule to get the `name` column?

Comment: Hi, the id is autoincrement

Answer (score 0):

[MySQL's Windows Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions.html) is what you need. Try this:

```
select distinct first_value(id) over (partition by autfis_id order by id), 
       autfis_id, 
       count(1) over (partition by autfis_id),
       name 
  from tablea;
```

Tested it with this script:

```
create database test;
use test;
create table tablea (id int, autfis_id int, name varchar(20));
insert into tablea values (1,1,'a');
insert into tablea values (2,1,'a');
insert into tablea values (3,2,'c');
insert into tablea values (4,1,'a');
insert into tablea values (5,2,'c');
insert into tablea values (6,3,'d');
```

Do keep in mind that if names differ, then you might get more rows than what you're expecting. But it's hard to tell when we don't know what the data structure is actually representing, and what are its expected values.

Comment: Thanks, But I forgot to mention my table has many other columns than "id", "autfis_id", "name". If possible  I´d like a solution to many columns. I just updated my question